# Publishing symbols to VSTS

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, azure-devops, dnx, azure-pipelines

I am using VSTS to build a xproj(dnx), the output is a set of a.nupkg with a.symbols.nupkg.

When i run the publish nuget package task it tries to upload all *.nupkg files to [VSTS package managment](https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/package/overview). So when ever it hits the first symbols package it gets a 409 Conflict error.

In my dev builds i have a script that creates the package version by appending "alpha-{buildnumber} at the end, so as an example it would look like this: 1.0.0-alpha-1

So my question is, how is the best way to handle the symbols packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manage to make it work by appending `-:**\\*.symbols.nupkg` to the default pattern in the VSTS Task.

Comment: This will become the default soon. https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/pull/1514